Request for a Well-Structured D&D Character Sheet in LaTeX
I’m currently looking for a more aesthetically pleasing and well-structured D&D character sheet template for LaTeX. I find the official ones somewhat lacking in terms of structure and visual appeal.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me create or suggest a LaTeX template that allows for easy updates via a YAML file, rather than manually adjusting the LaTeX code each time.
Here’s what I have in mind:

A LaTeX template: A nice-looking character sheet that is both visually appealing and well-organized.
A YAML file: A configuration file where I can input all the necessary data (I’ll provide the structure but not the content).

I want to focus on updating the YAML file with character data, and not have to deal extensively with the LaTeX code itself.
Here’s a minimal working example (MWE) of how I envision the YAML file and a basic LaTeX template to get started:
YAML File (character_data.yaml)
name: ""
class: ""
level: ""
background: ""
player_name: ""
race: ""
alignment: ""
experience: ""

attributes:
  strength: ""
  dexterity: ""
  constitution: ""
  intelligence: ""
  wisdom: ""
  charisma: ""

proficiencies:
  - ""
  - ""

skills:
  acrobatics: ""
  animal_handling: ""
  arcana: ""
  athletics: ""
  deception: ""
  history: ""
  insight: ""
  intimidation: ""
  investigation: ""
  medicine: ""
  nature: ""
  perception: ""
  performance: ""
  persuasion: ""
  religion: ""
  sleight_of_hand: ""
  stealth: ""
  survival: ""

equipment:
  - ""
  - ""

spells:
  level_1: 
    - ""
  level_2:
    - ""
  level_3:
    - ""
  level_4:
    - ""
  level_5:
    - ""

LaTeX Template (character_sheet.tex)
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{yaml}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\title{D&D Character Sheet}
\author{Character Name: \yaml{name}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section*{Character Details}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3in} \= \kill
Class: \> \yaml{class} \\
Level: \> \yaml{level} \\
Background: \> \yaml{background} \\
Player Name: \> \yaml{player_name} \\
Race: \> \yaml{race} \\
Alignment: \> \yaml{alignment} \\
Experience: \> \yaml{experience} \\
\end{tabbing}

\section*{Attributes}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2in} \= \kill
Strength: \> \yaml{attributes.strength} \\
Dexterity: \> \yaml{attributes.dexterity} \\
Constitution: \> \yaml{attributes.constitution} \\
Intelligence: \> \yaml{attributes.intelligence} \\
Wisdom: \> \yaml{attributes.wisdom} \\
Charisma: \> \yaml{attributes.charisma} \\
\end{tabbing}

\section*{Proficiencies}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{proficiencies[0]}
\item \yaml{proficiencies[1]}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Skills}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2in} \= \kill
Acrobatics: \> \yaml{skills.acrobatics} \\
Animal Handling: \> \yaml{skills.animal_handling} \\
Arcana: \> \yaml{skills.arcana} \\
Athletics: \> \yaml{skills.athletics} \\
Deception: \> \yaml{skills.deception} \\
History: \> \yaml{skills.history} \\
Insight: \> \yaml{skills.insight} \\
Intimidation: \> \yaml{skills.intimidation} \\
Investigation: \> \yaml{skills.investigation} \\
Medicine: \> \yaml{skills.medicine} \\
Nature: \> \yaml{skills.nature} \\
Perception: \> \yaml{skills.perception} \\
Performance: \> \yaml{skills.performance} \\
Persuasion: \> \yaml{skills.persuasion} \\
Religion: \> \yaml{skills.religion} \\
Sleight of Hand: \> \yaml{skills.sleight_of_hand} \\
Stealth: \> \yaml{skills.stealth} \\
Survival: \> \yaml{skills.survival} \\
\end{tabbing}

\section*{Equipment}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{equipment[0]}
\item \yaml{equipment[1]}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Spells}
\subsection*{Level 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{spells.level_1[0]}
\end{itemize}
\subsection*{Level 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{spells.level_2[0]}
\end{itemize}
\subsection*{Level 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{spells.level_3[0]}
\end{itemize}
\subsection*{Level 4}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{spells.level_4[0]}
\end{itemize}
\subsection*{Level 5}
\begin{itemize}
\item \yaml{spells.level_5[0]}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

Additionally, I found a D&D-style template on Overleaf that might be a good reference. Here is the link: Overleaf D&D Style Template.
I appreciate the general direction of the template, but I find it to be overly complex and requiring too many different files. Simplifying it could make it more user-friendly and efficient.
Additionally, I think a style similar to the one showcased in this video could be a good model. It demonstrates a more streamlined approach that could enhance clarity and usability.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if you can assist in creating a well-designed stylesheet that integrates with the YAML file for an easier character sheet update process.
Thank you!

If you want to use yaml, maybe look at the tempateiung engine provided by pandoc: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates
For the D&D part there is this excellent package https://ctan.org/pkg/rpgicons

Are you going to print the sheet or viewing it on a screen? If it is the latter, I think adding text fields, radio buttons or drop down menus would be easier to use (but uglier).

Hi, thanks. I won’t be printing them, but I’d appreciate help creating something visually appealing and well-structured. As mentioned, I’m not satisfied with the design and layout of the official version. I’d like assistance in developing a template that I can easily tweak later if needed. I’ll be inputting all the information using YAML and then compiling it.

welcome! I think this is too big a question for the format of this site which is really designed for much more focused questions.

I second cfr‘s note. Your question is more about personal taste, so your question could be closed due to this. This site is focused on technical aspects. So, maybe focus your question a bit, such as how to read in YAML or generate complex forms (but there might already be some similar questions on this site).

What I'm saying is you don't need a YAML to tweak things and recompile. Make a PDF with text fields and buttons, then the player can input all the information directly in the PDF, no need to tweak things from the LaTeX side.

Some questions+remarks: WHY do you chose Latex? // The DD template: Well, that's what you have to do one way or the other when you start modifying the look of a class ... while the data remain as they are. // Taste: was already mentioned. Be more specific about what you don't like with the DDtemplate, issue by issue. // Why YAML (which will need lualatex)? Define a set of \newcommand s and there you go.

Here is a simple starting point.
This way you focus first on content, which translates into the useful set of macros and text-entities. Build a demo-document step by step.
Later you can tweak and change any aspect of layout, like fonts, scribbled shapes, colors etc.

Macros instead of YAML
Using \newcommand, which is safer to use than \def from TeX, you define a set of useful macros. Basically they all do nothing but put out text (hence 0 paramters passed).
I suggest to use short enough names. The names can't contain digits ... so come up with sth speaking to you.
Absorb anything useful, like in the \spell macros. Make it simple (enough), but not simpler.
You call the macros as shown, best with the { }-es.
This is just a substitute to match your requirement, using the predefines from class article:
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{Character Name: \cname{}}

Tables
I showed an alternative using tabular. On ctan.org or here you'll find many more sophisticated table-packages, which can predefine column width etc.
Outlook
Once you know which macros you'll need, you can move them into a separate file and change the preampble like this, which gives you more or less the YAML functionality:
main.tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\input{cbarbaros}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{Character Name: \cname{}}
...

cbarbaros.tex
% ~~~ character features ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\cname   [0]{Barbaros}
\newcommand\cclass  [0]{barbar}
\newcommand\clevel  [0]{entry}
\newcommand\astrngth[0]{132}
\newcommand\aintell [0]{11}
\newcommand\spellA  [0]{Level 1: I wish you \dots}
\newcommand\spellB  [0]{Level 2: Fire shall burn you \dots}

It's also a good idea to have a look at using the concept of refactoring with Latex. P.S.: Here's a new Q&A on this subject: How to apply refactoring on Latex code?

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% ~~~ character features ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\cname   [0]{Barbaros}
\newcommand\cclass  [0]{barbar}
\newcommand\clevel  [0]{entry}
\newcommand\astrngth[0]{132}
\newcommand\aintell [0]{11}
\newcommand\spellA  [0]{Level 1: I wish you \dots}
\newcommand\spellB  [0]{Level 2: Fire shall burn you \dots}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title{Character Name: \cname{}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 
\section*{Character Details}
 \begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{3in} \= \kill
    Class: \> \cclass{} \\
    Level: \> \clevel{} \\
    \dots\\
 \end{tabbing}

\section*{Attributes}
 \begin{tabular}{lr}
    Strength:    & \astrngth\\
    Intelligence:& \aintell\\
    \dots \\
 \end{tabular}

\section*{Spells}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item \spellA{}
  \item \spellB{}
  \item \dots
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}


I think a link to a specific Q&A might be more useful? (I don't even know what 'refactoring' is. well, I have a general idea from the way people use it, so I expect I could make something up, but I don't suppose it would be conceptually correct.)

@cfr, May be. Do we have one Q&A on refactoring already?

actually, I was hoping you had one in mind which I could read :-).

Ok,let‘s see, tomorrow…

no, please don't search the proverbial haystack for a needle which might not even exist and is probably dodgy if it does. (pretty much all needles these days are dodgy, so the odds are not in our favour.)

@cfr, thank you for your hint and warning ... unless you've seen it already kindly have a look here, a new Q&A on refactoring in a Latex context: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725089/245790
